# What is the best way to work with a nodemailer with gmail?

Tags: node.js, gmail, sendgrid, nodemailer

Someone can tell how to configure the smtp server. Used nodemailer and host (smtp.gmail.com). Everything worked fine until it was released to production, and there the server is located in another country and Google requires two-factor authentication through a token with a timeout (a bad option), began to use others like sendgrid, it began to be sent normally on a remote server, but they did not go to gmail are coming. Started through local smtp server, like the server prints that the letter is gone. But I did not receive a letter to the box. Can someone help how to solve this issue?

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'info@gmail.com',
        pass: 'ddd1904)',
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
}));

const ownerMailTemplate = (entity, csv) => ({
    from: 'no-reply@samesoft.network',
    to: entity.email,
    subject: 'Subscribing samesoft service ✔',
    html: '<h4>Good day, Sergio!</h4>'
        + '<p>Congratulations! We have a new subscriber.</p>'
        + '<p>We have a combined 10 experience in the industry</p>',
    attachments: [{
        filename: 'emails.csv',
        content: csv
    }],
});

      const message = await transporter.sendMail(ownerMailTemplate({ email: OWNER_EMAIL }, csv));
      console.log("Message sent to owner: %s", message);
```